# Copy content from an html tag in a file to a tag in another html file

Tags: javascript, django

all in peace?
In Django, I need the content of an HTML tag to appear in another template. Using the code JS:

```
<script>
  var source = document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = source;
</script>

<div id="teste">context</div>
<div id="texto"></div>
```

It even works in the same template, but if the destination tag is in another template, it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because the JavaScript can't persist the data across to another file.

When a user visits, `/home` your HTML and JS is being sent to the client for that route only, so the route `/about` can't see what content is on the route `/home`. You've not said if this data is being retrieved from the server, so I'm going to assume it's not and let's look at a simple way to store data and access across routes using local storage (If a user accesses your site from another machine, they won't have access to the data. Also best not to store sensitive information and that it doesn't exceed 5 MB).

`/home route`

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<script>
  localStorage.setItem("name", "Jhon")
</script>
```

`/about route`

```
<h1>About</h1>
<p id="name"></p>
<script>
  const nameElement = document.getElementById("name");

  nameElement.textContent = localStorage.getItem("name")
</script>
```

This is only if you want / don't need to keep the data on the server. If not you would need to send that when you render the template.

Comment: Very grateful friend, the answer was clear. I'll try to upload to a server.

Comment: Finally I achieved the goal using global variable. Grateful.